# ClassNotFoundError в Web приложении

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, servlet, classloader

Всем привет. Стоит задача написать небольшой Rest-сервис на голых сервлетах.
Создавал проект в Intellij Idea следующим образом:

1. Создал Maven проект
2. Нажал правой кнопкой на проект -> Add Framework Support -> Java Ee Web App

Добавил зависимость в Pom.xml для Jackson:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Запускаю через Tomcat.

Создал тестовый сервлет, в нем создаю объект ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Вылетает исключение, что данного класса якобы нет в Class Path:

```
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
servlet.RegistrationServlet.doGet(RegistrationServlet.java:38)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoader    
Base.java:1344)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoader
```

При этом если создать отдельный класс, там метод main и запустить его, то объект создается нормально. Видимо проблема в этом класс-лоадере:
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase

Как бы так подружить его с моим Джексоном?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте обе зависимости.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

И на верхушке где :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>test_backend</artifactId>
```

Добавьте вот это.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я в итоге просто пересоздал проект с артефакта maven javaee web project - там уже был нормально заполненный pom-ник, с которым сразу все нормально работало. Думаю, Ваш ответ тоже бы помог.